# node.js to serve web page with access to resources on node.js server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server

I have an html page which references a number of local script files, and in turn those script files reference other local resources.  By local I mean local to the html file.

Is it possible to serve such a web page using a node.js server approach?  So far as I've been able to work out so far, the node.js server can return html content, but when that is displayed in the user's browser, I can't easily see how it would be able to reference the various scripts, because the html isn't being served from a normal folder on the server, with relative access to the folders and resources around it.

Is there any way of doing this, or is it mad to even contemplate such an approach?  Better just to stick the html and related resources on a standard server and be done with it?

EDIT: I should explain that the motivation for serving the html from node.js is that I'm already serving images from the node.js server, where those images are generated using the same scripts that the html will be using.  So there are two ways for the user to get the same content: as a png file or as a web page, and in both methods the work is done by the same core scripts... one has an html front end and the other has a node.js front end.  So it would be nice to be able to keep all the code in a single location, rather than having to duplicate stuff and have it in two places, and have to remember to update the code in the secondary location when I update it in the primary location.

EDIT to add folder structure to help debug this (see comments below):

```
mypage.html
myLibFile.js
/lib/*.js   (various js resources including jquery)
/lib/modules/*.js   (various js resources)
/lib/fonts/*  (various resources)
/themes/*.js  (various js resources)
```

In mypage.html I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery.1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/libFile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/modules/modFile.js"></script>
<link href="/lib/fonts/awesomefont.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myLibFile.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { // On DOM ready...
        // ... code ...
    });
</script>
```

and in my node.js I have attempted to set up express as follows:

```
self.app.use(express.static(__dirname));
self.app.use('/lib',  express.static(__dirname + '/lib'));
self.app.use('/themes',  express.static(__dirname + '/themes'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course your relative paths will work when using your own custom built nodejs server, which can serve files, .html .css .js and such.

I assume you have some sort of `public` folder from where you serve your assets. If you don't use any special routing magic, and just reffer to structure of your public folder, then relative paths in your HTML, will work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
```

Code above could load something like: `public/styles/main.css`

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion.  Say I have a node.js server listening at http://example.com/test  (I am using the express module as the basis for my node server).  The node server reads a local html file and returns that as the response.  So say in the html I have <script type="text/javascript" src="coolstuff.js"></script> -- how do I specify a public folder on the node.js server so that "coolstuff.js" will be read appropriately?

Comment: I am not developing using express.js, but this is something i found browsing the internet:

app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));

You basically should specify a static folder to serve your files, could you please show me your project's file structure? If you already serve your .html files from your apps, you can try putting other assets such as css/js to the same folder next to your html files.

Comment: OK looks promising.  Thanks.  I'll delve further into that.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there are any issues in serving html files from a static location on a node server, where the html files rely on jquery?  I have tried this out on my webpage, which is served just fine from a normal remote server, but from a static folder in a node.js server, it doesn't load as it should.

Comment: For further "debugging"  you should provide us with your folder structure, and more descriptive information of your issue. E.g what action you do, and what do you expect to happen + what happens in fact.

Comment: I have edited my original question to add folder structure and more about how I have attempted to set up the static resources within the express module.

Comment: OK I think my issue may in fact relate to a $.getJSON() call I make in my js code within the html file.  That is trying to access a remote page returning jsonp data, but I never get data returned.  Trying to figure out why this is happening when called within the node.js static server, and not on the normal server

Comment: Your questions/issues are not descriptive enough.

Comment: I've posted a new question with more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800552/getjson-call-from-express-static-html-file-doesnt-get-data