# $.getJSON() call from express static html file doesn't get data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I am using the express module as the basis for my node.js server, and set up a static middleware as follows:

```
self.app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

Within the root folder I have an html file that includes the following url to a php script on my remote server (completely different to the server hosting the node.js application) that returns jsonp data (having converted from xml data from the dataprovider):

```
var strURL = 'http://example.com/jsonp.php?callback=?&url=http://dataprovider.com/1.4/?arg1=xyz;arg2=abc';
```

And then a jquery getJSON call to actually get the json data:

```
$.getJSON(
        strURL,
        function (jsondata) {
            // do some stuff with the json data
        }
);
```

But when I load the html file that is being served from the static node.js folder, no data is returned... the code never reaches the jsondata function.

However, loading the very same html file placed on a "normal" server, the data is fetched just fine, and also if I load the strURL directly, the data is returned OK.

I suspect that this has something to do with cross domain issues, but for the life of me I can't get the page to work within the static node.js server using express.  I've tried various solutions out there, but am now thoroughly confused and frustrated!

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Have had cross domain issues with JSON in the past and got round them by using JSONP. There is a good explanation and tutorial at:

http://json-jsonp-tutorial.craic.com/index.html

Comment: However, so far as I understand, I *am* already using JSONP.  The php script at strURL returns jsonp rather than json, and I think that getJSON requires a URL to jsonp data.  So I'm not sure what else I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just managed to find where I used this and the only difference I can see between what you have done and mine is that the callback=? is the last parameter on my query string, in your case after the url attribute. Crazy shot in the dark but the best that I can come up with.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck.  It's very frustrating that this doesn't work!